# Forbidden Url on accessing "domain?/python+anything"

Tags: php, url, cpanel

I am not a regular Cpanel user and experiencing a weird error.

```
noticeboard.skillmonks.com/course.php?Hyderabad/python+and+Django+frame+work+course/&pid=217
```

This Url gives me 403 error while

```
noticeboard.skillmonks.com/course.php?Hyderabad/ython+and+Django+frame+work+course/&pid=217
```

doesn't

I tried multiple ways and Find out that word "domain?/python+anything" gives me an error.
some cases

```
noticeboard.skillmonks.com/course.php?/python+anything/&pid=217 -error
noticeboard.skillmonks.com/course.php?/python/&pid=217 - works
noticeboard.skillmonks.com/course.php?/java/&pid=217 -works
```

This happens only in one case that is "/python+anything"
this happens to multiple websites in the same Cpanel.
I didn't find anything in .htaccess
I am using PHP 5.6

anchor tag

```
<a href='course.php?".urlencode($city)."/".urlencode($institute)."/".urlencode($mode)."/".urlencode($course)."+course/&pid=".$id."' class=''>view</a>
```

course.php

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['pid'])) {        
        $base_url = ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']=='on' ? 'https' : 'http' ) . '://' .  $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $url = $base_url . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        $url_components = parse_url($url); 
        parse_str($url_components['query'], $params); 
        $pid = $params['pid'];
    }else {
        header('location: index.php');
    }
    include "db/config.php";
    $id = $pid;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$id'";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query_run)) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run);
        $image = (!empty($row['photo'])) ? 'img/' . $row['photo'] : 'img/jav.jpg';
        $course = $row['course'];
        $institute = $row['institute'];
        $email = $row['email'];
        $location = $row['location'];
        $batch_date = $row['batch_date'];
        $batch_type = (!empty($row['batch_type'])) ? $row['batch_type'] : 'Regular';
        $demo_date = $row['demo_date'];
        $mode = $row['mode'];
     }

        ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head></head><body>php echo result here </body></html>
```

Comment: Please post your htaccess and `client.php`. In general, adding `?/python+anything` to an URL won't do anything special.

Comment: `RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [NC,L]` 
tried removing htaccess bus didn't worked and May I know what is client.php?
It worked perfectly in system localhost

Comment: I meant `course.php`, the file you're calling.

Comment: Just now added it. I think nothing wrong with it because it works fine for other courses. 
is there any chance that error with Cpanel because it happens the same with other domains inside the same Cpanel and only while "?/python+text"